# Can Gradle restart running app in continuous build mode run?

Tags: gradle

With `gradle run -t` my java application restarts nicely after exit whenever a src file changed. But can I use Gradle to terminate a running app and restart it?

I can see using `-d` that Gradle detects the change while my app is running.

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.filewatch.jdk7.WatchServiceFileWatcherBacking] Received file system event: FileWatcherEvent{type=MODIFY, file=/usr/src/app/src/main/java/App.java}
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.filewatch.jdk7.WatchServiceRegistrar] Calling onChange with event FileWatcherEvent{type=MODIFY, file=/usr/src/app/src/main/java/App.java}
```

But as [documented](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/continuous_build.html) restart requires that "the build task and its dependencies complete without error".

I'm running in Docker, hence the IDE's support for compile during run can't be used. For Node.js I use [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) for this kind of development setup.

Comment: Now also https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-restart-a-run-in-continuous-mode/23221

Comment: https://github.com/solsson/gradlemon

Answer (score 1):

I no longer think that this would make Java development any more efficient. See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-restart-a-run-in-continuous-mode/23221/11.