# Continuously building and running Gradle application using application plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Spring boot Gradle app with application plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.moowork.node' version '1.2.0'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    //a plugin to run the gradle application using command line: ./gradlew run
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.4.RELEASE'
}

mainClassName = 'com.boot.MyProject.MyApplication'
```

I run this project using `./gradlew -t run`. I'd like gradle to watch my project files and rebuilds the project and runs it if there is any change in its files. But it seems that merely using `-t` doesn't help.

Any idea how I should make this work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918632/can-gradle-restart-running-app-in-continuous-build-mode-run), it can't work if the app is still running. Gradle will detect the change but as the task (`run`) is not finished successfully, the restart won't be triggered.

It will only work well if the `run` task is finished before the change happens.